# How can I display a UIBarButtonItem without a border?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder, uibarbuttonitem

In IB I can select a UIBarButtonItem, set it to Plain, Custom and apply an Image and it looks fine in a UIToolbar or UINavigationBar.

When I try to do this in code, I get a border:

```
backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowBack"] 
                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                 target:self 
                                                 action:@selector(backButtonClicked:)];
```

How can I get a UIBarButtonItem without a border? I want it to be Plain and Custom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me (example for the leftButton):

```
 UIButton *bt=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [bt setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 30)];
 [bt setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backBT"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [bt addTarget:self action:@selector(popViewController:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 UIBarButtonItem *leftButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:bt];
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=leftButton;
```